# Macports Apache not starting at Mac OSN Snow Leopard boot

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, boot, apache-http-server, macports, launchd

Macports Apache2 is not starting at Mac OSX Snow Leopard boot. I've done the `launchctl` load command, the symlinks point to my

`/opt/local//etc/LaunchDaemeons/org.macports.apache2/org.macports.apache2.plist`

but it never starts. I can start it manually, works fine after that. It just won't load on startup.

My server is named in my `/opt/localapache2/conf/httd.conf`, I had read that sometimes makes a difference. I've done the `launchctl` unload and load trick, all with no results. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is it listed when you do a 'launchctl list' in Terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Show us the output of:

```
ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

...so we can verify your symlink, and show us the contents of the plist that your symlink points to.

(Please don't take this harshly, but if you typed as sloppily while creating the symlink as you did while while writing your question, you probably just have a broken symlink. :-)